# Write the expression in coordinates of the projection on W parallel to U

Tags: linear-algebra, projection

Consider the following subspaces of $\in R^{3}$.

$U: x_{1}+2x_{2}+3x_{3}=0$

$W= span$ {$(1, -1, 1)$}

Show that $\in R^{3}= W \bigoplus U$ and write the expression in coordinates of the projection on $W // U$

After deducing the span of the subspace $U$ I've verified the linear independency by

$a(1,-1,1) + b(-2,1,0) + c(-3, 0, 1)= (0,0,0)$ $\leftrightarrow a=b=c=0$

Then, I concluded that $W \cap U=0$

So, consequently for the dimension theorem we have that $ R^{3}= W \bigoplus U$

Now, I'm having problems with the second part of the exercise.

I would be very thankful if someone can explain me **geometrically** what does it mean a projection on $W$ parallel to $U$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geometrically we start out from a point $v\in\Bbb R^3$ and move it parallelly with $U$ to arrive to a point $P(v)$ in $W$.
Put in other words, $P(v)$ is the intersection of $W$ and the *affine* subspace (plane in this case) $U+v$, which is a unique point if $\Bbb R^3=U\oplus W$.

Algebraically we can simply define $P(v)=P(u+w)=w$ where $u\in U,\,w\in W$ are the unique elements satisfying $v=u+w$.

Now either you directly calculate $P(e_i)$ for the standard basis vectors $e_1,e_2,e_3$, or write up the matrix of $P$ in the basis you found and apply basis transformation.